# What is the difference between senmorta and senmortulo?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

I can't quite understand the difference difference between "senmorta" and "senmortulo".

From what I understood the first would apply to anything that might be immortal, example;  "la senmorta principo" or "La korpo estas mortema, la animo estas senmorta".
The second applies directly and necessarily to a person, when refering to someone that is (or supposedly is) imortal, example "unu nura senmortulo" or "Urbo de la Senmortuloj".

**Is this the right meaning of these words?**

*Additional info:
I want to use this as an title or epitet of a character, like "Mateso, la Senmortulo", which could be simply called "Senmortulo" or "La senmortulo", similarly to how Superman is also called "The Man of Steel".*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jes, vi pravas. Tiuj estas la signifoj.

[`senmorta`](https://vortaro.net/#senmorta_kd) estas adjektivo, ĝi aplikeblas al io/iu kiu ne mortas, pereas, malaperas.

`senmortulo` estas estaĵo, kiu ne mortos. Notu ke [`ulo`](https://vortaro.net/#ulo_kd) *kutime* rilatas personon, sed ne nepre.

Vi povas pensi pri similar paroj de adjektivoj kun kaj sen `-ul-`. Ekzemple `dika` kaj `dikulo`.

Comment: Here are some _uloj_ which are not humans. Space science-fiction films have often _eksterteruloj_ and _zombioj estas senmortuloj, ĉar ili jam mortis_.